# How to check parent element is div or font and return fontsize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the parent element is font, I try to return its font size, but I am failing to check if it's a font or a div for the return value.

I try:

```js
function changeFont() {
  var font = GetFont().split('px')[0];
  var realFont = parseInt(font) + parseInt(50)
  alert(realFont);
  document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "7");
  var fontElements = document.getElementsByTagName("font");
  for (var i = 0, len = fontElements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (fontElements[i].size == "7") {
      fontElements[i].removeAttribute("size");
      fontElements[i].style.fontSize = realFont +"px";
    }
  }
}

function GetFont() {
  var a = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement;
  alert(a);
  var font = '0px';
  // If parent is font, return font size
  // I need help to return the font size
  return font;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="changeFont()" value="Change font">
<div contenteditable="true">Hello, this is some editable text</div>
```

Comment: what is `fontElements` and `i` - they don't seen to be declared in your code

Comment: there is no parent element for input on which your complete js is running. so what you trying actually (that's why it's not working)?

Comment: If parent is font I want to return font size. First time it is div  so no need to return just return 0px second time it is font so want to return fontsize in px .Please select and click a button you can see alert.

Comment: you dont have a parent child relation in you html. The input and div are siblings

Comment: .Please select a contain and click a button you can see alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many attempts I got it:

```js
function changeFont() {
  var font = GetFont().split('px')[0];
  var realFont = parseInt(font) + parseInt(50)
  //alert(realFont);
  document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "7");
  var fontElements = document.getElementsByTagName("font");
  for (var i = 0, len = fontElements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (fontElements[i].size == "7") {
      fontElements[i].removeAttribute("size");
      fontElements[i].style.fontSize = realFont + "px";
    }
  }
}

function GetFont() {
  var font = '0px';
  var tagName = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement.tagName;
  if (tagName == 'FONT') {
    tagName = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement;
    font = $(tagName).css('font-size');
  }
  return font;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="changeFont()" value="Change font">

<div contenteditable="true">Hello, this is some editable text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). This method gives the values of all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

So for the `font-size` you can do:

`window.getComputedStyle(element, pseudo-element or null).getPropertyValue('font-size');`

```js
function changeFont() {
  var font = GetFont().split('px')[0];
  //console.log(font);
  var realFont = parseInt(font) + parseInt(50)
  alert(realFont);
  document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "7");
  var fontElements = document.getElementsByTagName("font");
  for (var i = 0, len = fontElements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (fontElements[i].size == "7") {
      fontElements[i].removeAttribute("size");
      fontElements[i].style.fontSize = realFont + "px";
    }
  }
}

function GetFont() {

  var a = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement;

  var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(a, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');

  alert(fontSize);
  //var font = '0px';
  // if parent is font return fontsize 
  //  need help to return fontsize
  if (a.tagName !== "FONT") {
    fontSize = '0px';
  }
  return fontSize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="changeFont()" value="Change font">
<div contenteditable="true">Hello, this is some editable text</div>
```

Comment: getComputedStyle gives some browser compatibility problem. Thanks for help. I up-vote your answer.

Comment: If you are using `jQuery`, you can use `$(a).css("fontSize")` to get the font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tagName` to check if it is a div.

```
function GetFont() {
  var a = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement;
  var font;
  if (a.tagName == 'DIV') {
    font = '0px';
  } else {
    font = a.style.fontSize;
  }
  return font;
}
```